# Repeated values from a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

How do I incorporate a loop to repeat arguments in a function?

Let's say I have a function, `repeat` that takes two arguments, with the second argument is a `number`. I want the function to return as many arrays equal to the amount of the number that was passed as an argument. The only values that the array can contain are values that ae identical to the value in the first parameter.

```
let test = 'test'
let repeat = function(test, 3){

    //loop

}
```

I want the output to work like this:

`repeat('test, 3)` shall return an array like `['test', 'test', 'test']`

Comment: In es6 you could do `let repeat = (test, amount) => Array(amount).fill(test);` or just `Array(3).fill("test");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of several ways:

```
let repeat = function(test, N) {
  // Array constructor takes an argument, the length of the array to be created
  // .fill then fills the whole array with whatever is in the test variable
  return new Array(N).fill(test);

  // You can also use Array.from() if you prefer
  return Array.from({ length: N }).fill(test); 
}
```

You can find the documentation about `Array.fill` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), about the `Array` constructor [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) and about `Array.from` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).